# Ask for FileSystem permission

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, filesystems

Win10 1809 seems to behave differently than 1803 when you start your UWP app through Visual Studio.

- 1803 Default set to "On"
- 1809 sometimes reverts back to "Off"

Is there any way to ask the user for permission if this is set to "Off"? - Something similar to what can already be done with the "pin to taskbar" maybe?

[image: Img]

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only thing you can do is including an Hyperlink to that settings page, adding some explanation text about the reasons on why the user should select “On”.

That’s it.

What I’m writing is exactly the hint included in Microsoft Docs.